# Get versions when using GetListItem in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Currently I am retrieving list items from a sharepoint list via the provided web services and populate a asp.net web form.

My question is if it's possible to get different versions of a list item (provided they have more than one)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as far as i know there is no easy way. But, if you really really need this you could try to do this:

1. Enumerate all file versions using [Versions.GetVersions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/versions.versions.getversions%28v=office.12%29.aspx) web service
2. Get specific version by calling FrontPage RPC method ["get document"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442345.aspx)

The tricky part would be to get the url for a generic list item (for a normal file - it is quite straightforward). I would try something like Lists/Announcements/1_.000 , where Lists/Announcements is the *web-relative* url of your List, 1 is ListItemId and _.000 is just a constant suffix.

In practice, we used get document method to download a specific version of a document (not a list item). In theory it should work for generic list items too.

Here is also a [link](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2009/09/downloading-content-from-sharepoint-let.html) with a useful code sample calling "get document" method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work. Maybe I'll add two columns to the list, (GUID and version number) and when I save an item from the web form I create a GUID and set it to version number 0. When I select this item and populate the form I keep the GUID and version number in hidden labels and on "update" I actually insert a new record with the same GUID and version number i++. There won't be more versions than 4-5 (absolute max) so maybe we have to live with a bit of redundancy. Thanks for the links anyway.